# Using ubuntu classic window manager from USB drive

Tags: 11.04, window-manager, usb-drive

I am using ubuntu 11.04 from a live USB disk. I created some space on the USB for saving modifications during installation to the USB. I want the default window manager to be ubuntu classic. How can I do this?

Comment: It is not a duplicate. The link is for when you are using it from ordinary boot. So the crucial part is how to logout. I found a way though. Under the power icon, there is "switch from ubuntu" menu.

Comment: OK - you've answered your own question.  Good news

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. I found a way to do it. From the power icon on the right, there is a "switch from ubuntu..." menu. Use that to logout. On the login screen, login with username "ubuntu" and password as blank.